# Convert string to byte getting number format exception

Tags: java

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String str = "100.00";
        Short sObj2 = Short.valueOf(str);
        System.out.println(sObj2);
     }
}
```

Getting below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100.00"                                                                                          
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)                                                                                        
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)                                                                                                                         
        at java.lang.Short.parseShort(Short.java:118)                                                                                                                           
        at java.lang.Short.valueOf(Short.java:174)                                                                                                                              
        at java.lang.Short.valueOf(Short.java:200)                                                                                                                              
        at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:5)
```

How to resolve above issue?

Comment: `100.00` is not a valid `short`.  Do you mean to use `float` or `double`?

Comment: A Short is not a byte.  A Short holds integer values from -32,768 to 32,767 (inclusive).  Trying to parse a floating point value into an integer datatype causes this exception.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have above string "100.00" and I need to convert it into short. What are the possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

First a Short is not a byte (your question summary indicates you are trying to convert a string to a byte). A Short holds integer values from -32,768 to 32,767 (inclusive). Trying to parse a floating point value into an integer datatype causes this exception.

If you simply want code that will run without an exception, either of the following should work:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        String str = "100";
        Short sObj2 = Short.valueOf(str);
        System.out.println(sObj2);
    }
}
```

This first example makes it run by changing the string to an integer value.

or

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        String str = "100.00";
        Double sObj2 = Double.valueOf(str);
        System.out.println(sObj2);
    }
}
```

This second one works by parsing a string representing a floating point value into a variable type that supports floating points.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String str = "100";
Short sObj2 = Short.valueOf(str);
```

or if you **want to deal with decimal** values,

```
String str = "100.00";
Float fObj2 = Float.valueOf(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, as your post title suggests, you want to convert from a String data type to a byte data type. This doesn't necessarily include just displaying the a value which doesn't generate a **NumberFormatException** error. I'm assuming you actually want to work with those particular data types.

To throw a small twist into things, you want to convert all this from a string representation of a numerical value which can be from either a float or double data type ("100.00"). It's this decimal point within the numerical string that throws a glitch into things when doing any conversion and therefore needs to be handled before doing any such thing.

**Some things to consider:**

As a String, you can represent any number you like in any format you like. It can be as big as you want and it can be as small as you want. I can even be a number that is imaginary or doesn't exist, but the bottom line is....it will always be a String and you can do such things with String data types. Converting a String numerical value to an actual numerical data type such as byte, short, integer, long, double, float, etc is a different ball game altogether. Some String numerical values are easy to convert and yet some require more specific attention to detail.

A **byte** data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

A **short** data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive).

The **int** (integer) data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2147483648 and a maximum value of 2147483647.

The **long** data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed long has a minimum value of -9223372036854775808 and a maximum value of 9223372036854775807.

At the end of it all these four data types all maintain **integer** values with each data type also maintaining a minimum and maximum of values. You need to also consider this to some extent when doing data type conversions. If you are going to create a conversion method to convert from one data type to another you need to ensure that you do not exceed that minimum and maximum allowable value for the data type you want to convert to. Not a big deal if you want to convert a **byte** data type to a **short** data type or a **short** to an **integer** since we know that  the lesser will always play in the larger but this is not necessarily so when a larger is to play in a lesser (**short** to **byte**).

Your conversion method needs to check the value to convert so as to ensure it will actually fit into the desired data type. Java has constants to assist you with this so that you don't have to remember these minimums and maximums, for example: **Integer.MIN_VALUE** and **Integer.MAX_VALUE** or **Byte.MIN_VALUE** and **Byte.MAX_VALUE**.

When dealing with numerical strings you may also want to ensure that the string you're dealing with is actually a string representation of a numerical value and not a alphanumeric value such as that of a Hexidecimal string or just a plain out entry error whereas a character other than a digit has crept into the string somehow. In my opinion, the string: **"100.00"** is a string representation of both a alphanumeric value (because of the period) and a numeric value since it is a string representation of a double data type. What it will truly be depends upon how you handle the period (decimal point) in the string within your conversion method.

Let's take another look at that string value ("100.00"). Another thing you may want to consider is, what if our string value was: "100.74"? How do you want to handle this particular value? Do you want to ***Round Down*** to 100 or ***Round Up** to 101 before you convert it to a data type that requires a integer value?

Let's convert the String representation of the value "100.00" to a **short** data type. Now keep in mind that the methods I provide below by default will always convert a string representation of a double data type (if supplied) **downwards**, for example 100.45 or 100.99 will be 100. If you want to properly round up or down for this type of value then supply a boolean ***true*** in the optional **roundUpDown** argument:

```
private short StringToShort(final String input, final boolean... roundUpDown) {
    // Make sure there no dead whitespaces...
    String inputValue = input.replaceAll(" ", "");
    int i = 0;    // default return value is 0
    // If inputValue contains nothing ("") then return 0 
    if(inputValue.equals("")) { return 0; }

    // Is inputValue an actual numerical value?
    // Throws an exception if not.
    // Handles negative and decimal point...
    if (!inputValue.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\nStringToShort() Method Error!\n"
                + "The value supplied is not numeric (" + inputValue + ").\n");
    }

    // Was the optional roundUpDown argument supplied?
    boolean round = false;  // default is false
    if (roundUpDown.length > 0) { round = roundUpDown[0]; }

    // Convert the String to a Integer value
    if (inputValue.contains(".")) {
        // Must be a double type representation supplied
        Double value = Double.parseDouble(inputValue);
        if (round) { i = (int) Math.round(value); }
        else { i = (int) value.intValue(); }
    }
    else {
        // Must be a Integer type representation supplied
        i = Integer.parseInt(inputValue);
    }

    // Is the Integer value now too small or too 
    // large to be a Short data type?
    if (i > Short.MAX_VALUE || i < Short.MIN_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\nStringToShort() Method Error!\n"
                + "The value supplied is too small or too large (" + inputValue + ").\n"
                + "Only values from " + Short.MIN_VALUE + " to " + Short.MAX_VALUE 
                + " are allowed!\n");
    }

    // Finally, cast and return a short data type...
    return (short) i;
}
```

If you read all the comments within the code you can see that we've covered all the issues discussed above. Now, according to your post title, you wanted to convert to byte. Well, it's pretty much the very same method but with perhaps five or so small changes done, see if you can spot them:

```
private byte StringToByte(final String input, final boolean... roundUpDown) {
    // Make sure there no dead whitespaces...
    String inputValue = input.replaceAll(" ", "");
    int i = 0;    // default return value is 0
    // If inputValue contains nothing ("") then return 0 
    if(inputValue.equals("")) { return 0; }

    // Is inputValue an actual numerical value?
    // Throws an exception if not.
    // Handles negative and decimal point...
    if (!inputValue.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\nStringToByte() Method Error!\n"
                + "The value supplied is not numeric (" + inputValue + ").\n");
    }

    // Was the optional roundUpDown argument supplied?
    boolean round = false;  // default is false
    if (roundUpDown.length > 0) { round = roundUpDown[0]; }

    // Convert the String to a Integer value
    if (inputValue.contains(".")) {
        // Must be a double type representation supplied
        Double value = Double.parseDouble(inputValue);
        if (round) { i = (int) Math.round(value); }
        else { i = (int) value.intValue(); }
    }
    else {
        // Must be a Integer type representation supplied
        i = Integer.parseInt(inputValue);
    }

    // Is the Integer value now too small or too 
    // large to be a Byte data type?
    if (i > Byte.MAX_VALUE || i < Byte.MIN_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\nStringToByte() Method Error!\n"
                + "The value supplied is too small or too large (" + inputValue + ").\n"
                + "Only values from " + Byte.MIN_VALUE + " to " + Byte.MAX_VALUE 
                + " are allowed!\n");
    }

    // Finally, cast and return a byte data type...
    return (byte) i;
}
```